# Error 3 on PHP file transfer

Tags: php, file, http

I'm working on an application which send "home made" HTTP transfer to my webpage.

```
"POST /file.php HTTP/1.0\r\n"
"Host: xxxx.com\r\n"
"Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=\"Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\"\r\n"
"Content-Length:163\r\n"
"\r\n"
"--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\r\n"
"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"myfile.txt\"; content-Type:text/plain\r\n"
"\r\n"
"test"
"--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz--\r\n"
"\r\n"
```

This is my HTTP POST request. it seems fine, but when i execute the request and got the response, the PHP script file indicate an Error on the file : "3".
Meaning "UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL" but I don't know why it indicate such message. The payload length matches with the Content-Length value.

Could you help me ? 
Thank you.

Comment: Show the rest of your code. Not a single line of PHP in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your POST request is one missing CRLF in the boundary syntax.

The multipart/form-data is defined in [RFC7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578)
and the boundary syntax is described in [Section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578#section-4.1) as follows:

> As with other multipart types, the parts are delimited with a
> boundary delimiter, constructed using CRLF, "--", and the value of
> the "boundary" parameter.

Let's examine your current POST request.

```
POST /file.php HTTP/1.0
Host: xxxx.com
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary="Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Content-Length: 163

--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.txt"; content-Type:text/plain

test--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz--
```

Based on the specification, the last line should be two lines.
There must always be a CRLF and -- before every boundary, so that last line should be like this:

```
test
--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz--
```

Therefore the acceptable POST request is this:

```
POST /file.php HTTP/1.0
Host: xxxx.com
Content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary="Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Content-Length: 165

--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="myfile.txt"; content-Type:text/plain

test
--Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz--
```

I'm calling it "acceptable" because there is actually another mistake but it is minor.
My server simply ignores the minor mistake and accepts the request without a problem.

Comment: Thank you for the help. What is the "minor mistake" ? :)

Comment: @Flow There should be another CRLF right before Content-Type. Without it, the Content-Type is ignored.